# How to use _PAGE_BIT_SOFTW1?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, page-tables

There are a few bits in the PTE that are available for programmer.
For example, the following macros are defined in the linux kernel

```
// arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h
#define _PAGE_BIT_SOFTW1    9   /* available for programmer */
#define _PAGE_BIT_SOFTW2    10  /* " */
#define _PAGE_BIT_SOFTW3    11  /* " */
#define _PAGE_BIT_SOFTW4    58  /* available for programmer */
```

However, it seems that the 9th, 11th, and 58th bits are used by some code in the kernel.
I disabled some config and macro like the following so that those bits are not used by the code.

```
// arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h
#define __HAVE_ARCH_PTE_SPECIAL
#undef __HAVE_ARCH_PTE_SPECIAL // This is added by me.

// arch/Kconfig
#config HAVE_ARCH_SOFT_DIRTY
#   bool
```

After disabling those, I compiled kernel and got kernel error message.

```
ld:./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds:506: syntax error
Makefile:983: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

I want to use those bits.
How can I disable the code that is using those bits?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel does not use `_PAGE_BIT_SOFTW2`.

`_PAGE_BIT_SOFTW3` is used as a dirty bit. You can disable the code using it using [CONFIG_MEM_SOFT_DIRTY](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MEM_SOFT_DIRTY.html).

As far as I know, there is no easy way to prevent the kernel from using `_PAGE_BIT_SOFTW1` or `_PAGE_BIT_SOFTW4`.

Note that also in 4-level paging, bits 52-57 of all page table entries can also be used by the programmer. Linux doesn't seem to be using them.